# ionic4: ion-item border-top-left-radius, -top-right, -bottom-left, -bottom-right

Tags: css, sass, angular7, ionic4, shadow-dom

So, I've been doing a project with Ionic v4 and now I can't seem to get a border radius working, because I'm using classes to detect on an ngFor if it's the first item or the last item.

If its the first item, it should only change `top-left` and `top-right` border radius. And if it's the last item, it should only change `bottom-left` and `bottom-right` border radius.

Problem is: since it works with Shadow DOM I cannot apply that CSS.

What I did was:

**In my component.scss**

```
:host {
  ion-item {
    &.first {
      --border-radius: 12px;
      //   --border-top-left-radius: 12px;
      //   --border-top-left-radius: 12px;
      //   border-top-left-radius: 12px;
      //   border-top-left-radius: 12px;
    }
  }
}
```

But that's not what I want, the commented CSS won't work. And the only var to change that Shadow DOM styles are for the 4 `border-radius` according to the documentation: [ion-item Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item).

I've also tried to hardcore a `style` into the element but it won't work.

If someone can throw some light into this I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you considered just not using the shadow DOM on that component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `border-radius` property takes up to 4 different values.

The values are described in this order - first value applies to top-left corner, second value applies to top-right corner, third value applies to bottom-right corner, and fourth value applies to bottom-left corner.

```css
#example {
  border-radius: 50px 20px 30px 10px;
}
```

> You can get more information on the border radius property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)

More over, I think you are not selecting the first-child correctly

In a nested SCSS file, you'd rather type:

```css
&:first-child {
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  }
```

[Check this on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz4m8wfh/15/)

Comment: Oh my gosh, I hope my employer doesn't read my question, my mind was burnt when I asked this, you're totally right.